# Django Create object from within a model?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm developing a Django app part of which will be IP address allocation. As part of this I would like to be able to give user a list of available IP addresses which will be assigned to a ForeignKey (an object). I can use "ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24').hosts()" to get a list of available hosts within a subnet, question is:

- How would I assign it to say "available_ips" field?
- Also, how would I then assign a particular IP from this block to an object?
- Would I need another class for IP object and create them as part of "IPBlockAllocation" maybe?

Any advise would be much appreciated.

```
SUBNET_MASK = (
    (24, 24),
)

IP_BLOCK_ROLE = (
    ('Select', 'Select'),
    ('WAN', 'WAN'),
    ('LAN', 'LAN'),
    ('MGT', 'MGT')
)

class IPAddressAssignment(models.Model):
    parent_block = models.ForeignKey(
        'IPBlockAllocation', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.GenericIPAddressField(
        blank=True, null=True, unique=True, validators=[validate_ipv4_address])
    assigned_interface = models.ForeignKey(
        DeviceInterfaces, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class IPBlockAllocation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    prefix = models.GenericIPAddressField(
        blank=True, null=True, unique=True, max_length=12)
    mask = models.IntegerField(choices=SUBNET_MASK)
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=IP_BLOCK_ROLE, default='Select')
```

Comment: is `ipaddress` another Django model and how does it relate to `IPBlockallocation`?

Comment: `ipaddress` is standard Python module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html), i'm looking to check how many hosts there are in the submitted IP range (although at the moment subnet mask is only 24 so 253 usable). I kind of need a way of tracking IPBlockAllocation - > IPAssigned and ideally able to tell how may there are spare :-/

Comment: It woould start as a view with a form with a  ChoiceField initialized to the available IP addresses. When the form POSTed valid you would create and save an IPAddressAssignment instance, with parent_block set to the appropriate IPBlockAllocation object. If I understand correctly ....